# How to publish expo app to app center using EAS?

Tags: react-native, expo, release, appcenter, eas

Currently I'm using EAS to build my react native App however I don't need to publish the app in the Stores but in the App Center. I search in the Expo's docs but I didn't find how to do that in an easy way.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps to connect expo or eas with the following steps.

Create a new app in App Center: Go to the App Center dashboard and create a new app by clicking the "Add new app" button.

Configure EAS credentials: In your Expo project, add the `app.config.js` file if it doesn't exist already. Inside this file, add the following code:

```
export default {
  expo: {
    android: {
      package: 'com.your.package.name',
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY',
        },
        appSecret: {
          value: 'YOUR_APP_CENTER_SECRET',
        },
      },
    },
    ios: {
      bundleIdentifier: 'com.your.bundle.identifier',
      config: {
        googleMapsApiKey: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY',
        appSecret: 'YOUR_APP_CENTER_SECRET',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Replace com.your.package.name and com.your.bundle.identifier with your app's package and bundle identifiers, respectively. Replace `YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY` with your Google Maps API key, and `YOUR_APP_CENTER_SECRET` with your App Center app secret.

Install and configure the App Center CLI: Install the App Center CLI by running the following command:

`npm install -g appcenter-cli`

`appcenter login`

`eas build --platform all`

Replace `YOUR_APP_CENTER_APP_NAME` with your App Center app name, and provide release notes for your app in the `--description` parameter.

Deploy your app: Once your app is uploaded to App Center, you can deploy it to your users using the App Center portal. You can also configure App Center to automatically deploy new releases to specific distribution groups or to all users.
That's it! Your Expo app is now connected to App Center, and you can use App Center to manage your app's releases and distribution.